# Wordpress function wp_signon() always returns error

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to login a user using the Wordpress wp_signon() function but it always fails.

There are other questions similar to this, but they haven't solved this problem.

I have checked all the parameters which I passed and they are correct. Also when I login manually using these they work.

Below is the error I am getting:

**ERROR: Invalid username. Lost your password?**

And here's the code which I have placed in functions.php file and which triggers login.

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['status']) && $_REQUEST['status'] == 'success'){
    function custom_login_qhepstowgram() {
        if(!empty($_SESSION['custom-login-user']) && !empty($_SESSION['custom-login-pwd'])){
            $creds = array();
            $creds['user_login'] = $_SESSION['custom-login-user'];
            $creds['user_password'] = $_SESSION['custom-login-pwd'];
            $creds['remember'] = false;
            $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
            if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
                $_SESSION['errorMsg'] = $user->get_error_message();
            }
        }
    }

    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_login_qhepstowgram' );
}
```

I am searching for a solutions since hours, can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be sure: Did you try to log in using a different theme?

Comment: Are you ever clearing `$_SESSION['errorMsg']`?

Comment: @eevaa: I am only using a single theme and I haven't tried using a different theme.

Comment: @Pekka웃: Yes the error message is cleared after page loads so it doesn't show up again.

Comment: I was asking because actually something could be wrong with your username. Double check that.

Comment: @eevaa: Nope the username is fine. If I login manually it works.